# Is there any updated documentation for the field names and types for the system tables?

Tags: advantage-database-server

Is there any updated documentation for the field names and types for the Advantage Database system tables?

Comment: Online help can be found at http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=32.  Is there some specific information you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The Advantage help files are available online as Mark mentioned. The latest help files became available today. I included some links for the system tables which include the field definitions.

[system.tables](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/index.html?master_system_tables.htm)
[system.indexes](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/index.html?master_system_indexes.htm)
[system.functions](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/index.html?master_system_functions.htm)
[system.views](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/index.html?master_system_views.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help file pertain to version 9.1? 
I noticed a system.tables field, "Triggers_Disabled", that is not in the current documentation.